# Matlab: Reduce the spacing between symbols and labels in the legend

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure, legend-properties

When using the legend command in matlab, how can I reduce the horizontal distance between the legend symbols and their corresponding labels?

Example code:

```
Line1=plot(x1,y1,'s');
Line2=plot(x2,y2,'o');
Line3=plot(x3,y3,'^');
Leg=legend([Line1, Line2, Line3],...
           'Line1 text','Line2 text','Line3 text',...
           'Location','NorthEast');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the children of `Leg`, search for the ones that have their `Type` set to `text` and relocate them. Here is a code to show how to do that. It moves them to left by 0.2 which is relative to the legend box.

```
ch = get(Leg, 'Children');
textCh = ch(strcmp(get(ch, 'Type'), 'text'));
for iText = 1:numel(textCh)
    set(textCh(iText), 'Position', get(textCh(iText), 'Position') + [-0.2 0 0])
end
```

Comment: Thanks! this did exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why you want to do this but a possible solution could be:

```
clf;
hold on;
x=0:0.1:2*pi;
plot(x,sin(x),'s');
plot(x,cos(x),'o');
ax=legend('sin','cos');
LEG = findobj(ax,'type','text');
set(LEG,'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

You can test out `'center'` and `'right'` and use whichever works. If neither works, ignore my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Good Idea, but this causes the legend text to overlap with the symbols.  I am just trying to improve the readability of my plot, i feel as it is currently, there is just too much space between the legend text and the symbols